# CMSIS DSP in STM32CubeIDE

Tags: arm, stm32, cmsis, stm32cubemx

I want to use the DSP functions that are present in CMSIS. I'm using STM32CubeIDE with my target board being the ST32F411RE Discovery. Using CMSIS DSP with Keil uVision is extremely simple, you just select thew pack you want and use it but it's not so simple with STM32CubeIDE. CMSIS is included with the latest firmware pack STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.24.2 but there doesn't seem to be any option within CubeMX or the IDE to add the DSP libraries (which are present in the firmware pack). The CORE libraries are added by default. I have added the DSP Include and Source folders to my workspace, I have added the include paths to the IDE but when I add

`#include "arm_math.h` to main.c

I get an error telling me that

`fatal error: arm_math.h: No such file or directory` and it is directed at each DSP source file.

I've spent the last few days trying to get past this. Has anyone used the CMSIS DSP functions in STM32CubeIDE and if so, how have they managed to set up CMSIS DSP to work with the IDE? Are there any further things that I could try with my setup? I'm surpised that the integrated CubeMX code generator doesn't provide the option to include DSP.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: May be `../Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Include`?

Comment: It was as simple as that. @Bulkin was correct.

Answer (score 5):

this guy has the answer to your question:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCcALaGNlyw

ok, you have to spend 15 minutes to watch the video, but it's worth it, as he explains it pretty well.

TL/DW:

- download the library from github: https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5
- copy the lib into your project directory
- change the linker settings in the project properties to include the file

In Cube-MX click on "software packages" and activate CMSIS and DSP. Then you can select the packages for code generation ...

Requirements: the CMSIS package needs to beinstalled
this can be done by

- downloading the package form github
- open cubeMX and select "install from local"

Comment: What is meaning TL/DW

Comment: To Long / did not watch - a derivate from TL/DR "to long / did not read"